# Page factory initiation is not working returns java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item in appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android, page-factory

When I try to access my page objects I'm getting below error.

My `AbstractRepo.java` class:

```
public static WebDriver driver;

    public AbstractRepositary(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        //PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

**
 - *Enumerator.java*
**
public class Enumerator extends  AbstractRepositary{
    public static Enumerator enumerator = null;
    public Enumerator(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
```

Output exception are :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:372)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:380)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:376)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:376)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:376)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:540)
```

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Comment: Your PageFactory.InitElements in your page class is redundant and possibly harmful, as it is already being performed in the extended class when you call super(driver)

Comment: @BillHileman So your try to say that PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this); should be removed from my code?

Comment: Everywhere EXCEPT the base class itself, yes, since any class that extends the base class and calls `super((driver)` will call the initelements for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved but removing selenium-client from pom.xml as java-client internally calls Selenium.'
Refer: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/949